PyQt6 - allow streching for a particular widget
I'm a newbie to PyQt6. My problem is, I would like to have a window with different tabs and in the first tab "tab_1" the space is divided into 2 columns. The 1st column contains some options (for example filter, boxes etc.) and this column width should remain unchanged with the window size. The  2nd column inhibits a tabular and the number of visible columns differs with the window size.
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPalette, QColor


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.North)
        self.tabs.setMovable(False)

        # Tab 1
        self.tab_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab_1, "tab_1")
        self.tab_1_func()


        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

    def tab_1_func(self):
        """ Overview """
        
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        page_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.tab_1.stacklayout = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
       
        page_layout.addLayout(grid_layout)
        page_layout.addLayout(self.tab_1.stacklayout)
        #page_layout.addStretch(0)
        #page_layout.insertStretch(1,0)
        
        #
        # Left Column - Buttons, fitlers etc
        #

        widget_box = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        widget_box.addItems(['Country', 'Capital', 'Street'])
        grid_layout.addWidget(widget_box, 0, 0)
        
        # Widget 2: Line Input for Filter
        widget_filter = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        widget_filter.setPlaceholderText("Enter your text")
        grid_layout.addWidget(widget_filter, 0, 1)

        #grid_layout.setColumnMinimumWidth(1,300)
        grid_layout.setColumnStretch(3,1)

        
        # Widget 3: Data
        data = [
            ('France', 'Paris', 'Rue de X'),
            ('United Kingdom', 'London', 'Road X'),
            ('Italy', 'Rome', 'Strade X'),
            ('Germany', 'Berlin', 'Straße X')
        ]
        
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        N_row = 4
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(N_row) 

        N_column = 3
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(N_column)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Country', 'Capital', 'Street'])
        for row in range(N_row):
            for column in range(N_column):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[row][column])
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, item)

        # add the widget and connecting widgets together directly
        page_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        page_layout.addStretch(1)


        
        self.tab_1.setLayout(page_layout)

Currently, the only option I found to fix the 1st column is to set page_layout.addStretch(1) near the end. But this fix the size of tabular as well. It would be great to get a hint, what's my error here. Thanks.

Change to page_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, stretch=1) and remove page_layout.addStretch(1). Ensure that you properly read the whole documentation about layout managers and its classes (in this case, specifically, QBoxLayout which is the base class from which QHBoxLayout and QVBoxLayout inherit). Also, do some experiments with layouts in Qt Designer in order to better understand their behavior interactively.

@musicamante Thank you very much for your fast reply and it worked. I will proceed as proposed. Cheers
